# (Bash) Editing contents of array from within function

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to pad all the items of an array to 20 characters with whitespace, but can't seem to get my loop to work properly. It appears to increment through the array items correctly, but does not alter the items. Where am I going wrong here?

```
#!/bin/bash

testArray=( "bish" "bash" "bosh")

padLine () {
array=( "${@}" )
testLength=20
counter=0

##loop begins here##
for i in "${array[@]}";
do
size=${#array[$counter]}
testLength=20

#echo ""
#echo "size: " $size
#echo "Tlength: " $testLength
#echo "count: " ${array[$counter]}
#echo ""

if [ $size -lt $testLength ]
then 
    offset=$( expr $testLength - $size )

    #echo "Offset: " $offset

    case $offset in
        0)
            l0=""
            ;;
        1)
            l1=" "
            array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l1};;
        2)
            l2="  "
            array[$counter]="${array[$counter]/%/$l2}";;
        3)
            l3="   "
            array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l3};;
        4)
            l4="    "
            array[$counter]="${array[$counter]/%/$l4}";;
        5)
            l5="     "
            array[$counter]="${array[$counter]/%/$l5}";;
        6)
            l6="      "
            array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l6};;
        7)
            l7="       "
            array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l7};;
        8)
            l8="        "
            array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l8};;
        9)
            l9="         "
            array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l9};;
        10)
            l10="          "
            array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l10};;
        11)
            l11="           "
            array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l11};;
        12)
            l12="            "
            array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l12};;
        13)
            l13="             "
            array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l13};;
        14)
            l14="              "
            array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l14};;
        15)
            l15="               "
            array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l15};;
        16)
            l16="                "
            array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l16};;
        17)
            l17="                 "
            array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l17};;
        18)
            l18="                  "
            array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l18};;
        19)
            l19="                   "
            array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l19};;

        *)
    esac
fi
counter=$( expr $counter + 1 )  
done
}

padLine "${testArray[@]}"


echo -e "${testArray[0]}" 
echo -e "${testArray[1]}"
echo -e "${testArray[2]}"
```

Expected output:

```
bish                #lines end here, padded to 20 chars
bash                #                
bosh                #
```

Actual output:

```
bish# no padding
bash
bosh
```

Answer (score 6):

Just for output:

```
array=( bish bash bosh )
printf '%-20s#\n' "${array[@]}"
```

This would produce

```
bish                #
bash                #
bosh                #
```

... where `#` occurs in column 21.

To make a new array (and printing it):

```
array=( bish bash bosh )

for elem in "${array[@]}"; do
    padarr+=( "$( printf '%-20s#' "$elem" )" )
done

printf '%s\n' "${padarr[@]}"
```

With `/bin/sh`, just printing:

```
set -- bish bash bosh
printf '%-20s#\n' "$@"
```

With `/bin/sh`, modifying `$@` in-place:

```
set -- bish bash bosh
i=0
while [ "$i" -lt "$#" ]; do
    set -- "$@" "$( printf '%-20s#' "$1" )"
    shift
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done

printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

The `printf` formatting string `%-20s` reserves 20 characters for a left-justified string.

---

As a `bash` (4.3+) function:

```
pad_array () {
    local padlen=$1
    local -n localarray=$2

    local -a tmp
    local elem

    for elem in "${localarray[@]}"; do
        tmp+=( "$( printf '%-*s#' "$padlen" "$elem" )" )
    done

    localarray=( "${tmp[@]}" )
}

myarray=( bish bash bosh )
pad_array 20 myarray

printf '%s\n' "${myarray[@]}"
```

The `pad_array` function here additionally allows you to choose the amount of padding.

The array is passed by its name and is received by the function in a name reference variable.  This means that whenever the name reference is accessed in the function, the named variable are actually used.

Comment: Note that `printf %-20s` pads to 20 bytes, not characters in `bash` which would make a different for multi-byte characters. See also `printf -v` in `bash` to avoid the cmdsubst.

Comment: Note that the nameref variant could change the indices of the array. An array defined as `a([5]=x [12]=y)` would end up as `a([0]="x ..." [1]="y ...")`

Answer (score 4):

If switching to `zsh` is an option:

```
$ array=(foo bar bàz '')
$ padded_array=(${(r:20:)array})
$ printf '<%s>\n' $padded_array
<foo                 >
<bar                 >
<bàz                 >
<                    >
```

Note that that `(r:20:)` right-padding parameter expansion flag pads but also truncates to 20 characters for strings that are longer.

Another option with `zsh` is to do:

```
padded_array=()
(($#array)) && printf -v padded_array '%-20s' "$array[@]"
```

Contrary to `bash`, the padding is done character-wise as opposed to byte-wise and `zsh` supports array arguments to the `-v` option.

Note that if `$array` contains just one element, `$padded_array` is converted to scalar.

For padding+truncating, replace `%-20s` with `%-20.20s`.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing two mistakes.

1. You're passing `testArray` to the function, then you create the new array in the function, you modify it, but you finally print out the first array. You want to print the modified results, right?
2. Your script doesn't do what you expect, because you use this construct:

   ```
    array[$counter]=${array[$counter]/%/$l16}
   ```

   This is the pattern substitution of general form `${parameter/pattern/string}`. You don't need to substitute anything. You have the suffix ready at this point, just need to append it like:

   ```
   array[$counter]="${array[$counter]}${l16}"
   ```

You can access the array `array` outside of the function, as the array is not declared as local. So you can just use:

```
echo -e "${array[0]}"
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

To pass variables by reference in `bash` 4.3+, you can use `typeset -n`:

```
pad_array() {
  typeset -n _array="$1"
  typeset _n="$2" _pad _i
  printf -v _pad '%*s' "$_n"

  for _i in "${!_array[@]}"; do
    ((${#_array[_i]} < _n)) || continue # remove this line to also truncate
    _array[_i]+=$_pad
    _array[_i]=${_array[_i]:0:_n}
  done
}

array=(foo b bàz '')
pad_array array 20
```

The `typeset -n` *nameref* feature comes from `ksh93` however note that contrary to in `ksh93`, the above won't work to pad array variables whose name is used in the function (hence the underscore prefix for them to limit the risk of clashing).

Answer (score 0):

If you’re willing to place an arbitrary upper limit
on the number of spaces to add
(and you obviously are,
as your `case` statement can’t handle a length greater than 20),
and you’re just talking about bytes
(and not *characters*, which can be multi-byte),
a simple way to pad a variable to a given length is:

```
# 75 spaces
spaces="                                                                           "
    ︙
length=20
    ︙
newValue=$(expr substr "$value$spaces" 1 "$length")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Core idea

```
for elem in "${localarrayname[@]}"; do
    localtoarray+=(   "$(printf '<%-*.*s>\n' "$p" "$p" "$elem")"   )
done
```

#### Simple var

Using printf to add a variable count of spaces is very simple (the asterisk is the count):

```
$ printf '<%-*s>'   8   hello    ; echo
<hello   >
```

It could even be used to either extend or cut an string to a count:

```
$ printf '<%-*.*s>'   8 8   "TestingHello"    ; echo
<TestingH>
```

#### Fixed trailing string

Using variable substitution we can add a fixed string to a variable:

```
$ var=hello
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${var/%/"xxx"}"
<helloxxx>
```

That could be expanded to an array of values:

```
$ var=( hello world test )
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${var[@]/%/"xxx"}"
<helloxxx>
<worldxxx>
<testxxx>
```

#### Array of values.

However, to add a variable count of spaces to an array we need to use a loop.
We can use a function to pass the list of values (only printing):

```
padarray(){ p=$1; shift
            for elem; do
                printf '<%-*.*s>\n' "$p" "$p" "$elem"
            done
          }

array=( foo qux quuux alongerstring )
padarray 15 "${array[@]}"
```

It prints:

```
$ ./script
<foo            >
<qux            >
<quuux          >
<alongerstringto>
```

#### Indirect array.

To pass the arguments to a new array using the array(s) names (indirect):

```
padarray(){ local p=$1;
            local -n localarrayname=$2 localtoarray=$3
            localtoarray=()
            for elem in "${localarrayname[@]}"; do
                localtoarray+=(   "$(printf '<%-*.*s>\n' "$p" "$p" "$elem")"   )
            done
          }

array=( foo qux quuux alongerstringtotest )
padarray 12 array paddedarray
printf '%s\n' "${paddedarray[@]}"
```

Which on execution prints a similar result:

```
$ ./script
<foo         >
<qux         >
<quuux       >
<alongerstrin>
```

#### Better pad count.

Adding a more robust count number of padding characters (`$p`):

```
p=${1//[!0-9]}                    # Select only numeric digits.
(( 0<=p && p<=999 )) && return 2  # Return on error. Count out of range.
```

## Final

We end with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

padarray(){ local p=${1//[!0-9]}                       # Select only numeric digits.
            p=${p:-20}                                 # Make the default count = 20.
            local -n localarrayname=$2 localtoarray=$3 # Define indirect (local) array names.
            localtoarray=()                            # Clean the resulting array.
            (( 0<=p && p<=999 )) || return 2           # Return on error. Count out of range.
            for elem in "${localarrayname[@]}"; do
                localtoarray+=(   "$(printf '<%-*.*s>\n' "$p" "$p" "$elem")"   )
            done
          }


array=( bash bish bosh "" foo qux quuux "A Longer String To Test" )
padarray 20 array paddedarray
printf '%s\n' "${paddedarray[@]}"
```